# Duda escribir palabras al reves de una lista en python

Tags: python-3.x

he visto varias respuestas en otros hilos sobre frases o palabras al revés, el problema es que cuando realizo esto en una lista de palabras no sale lo que estoy buscando.

lista_palabras = ["casa","arbol", "mesa","silla","teclado","raton","telefono","llaves","guantes","tijeras"]

Lo que busco es que esten escritas al reves por ejemplo ["asac","lobra"....*]

mi codigo es:

```
for palabra in lista_palabras[::-1]:
    print(palabra)
    x=palabra
    for letra in palabra[::-1]:
        print(letra)
        #lista_reverse.append(letra)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python es maravilloso. Buena elección de lenguaje:

```
lista_palabras = ["casa","arbol", "mesa","silla","teclado","raton","telefono","llaves","guantes","tijeras"]
lista_reverse = []
for palabra in lista_palabras:
    lista_reverse.append(palabra[::-1])
    print(palabra, lista_reverse[-1])
```

Con el `for` recorro las palabras de la lista en su orden normal.

Si tengo un string `x`, todo lo que tengo que hacer para invertirlo es usar esta *rebanada de lista* `[::-1]`, y eso sería todo.

#### Demo

```
lista_palabras = ["casa","arbol", "mesa","silla","teclado","raton","telefono","llaves","guantes","tijeras"]
lista_reverse = []
for palabra in lista_palabras:
    lista_reverse.append(palabra[::-1])
    print(palabra, lista_reverse[-1])
```

produce:

```
casa asac
arbol lobra
mesa asem
silla allis
teclado odalcet
raton notar
telefono onofelet
llaves sevall
guantes setnaug
tijeras sarejit

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, me has hecho facil lo dificil jajaj un saludo!

Comment: @David. No soy yo, es Python.